# Difference between ip addr and ifconfig?

Tags: networking, ip, ip-address, subnets

If it's subnet then it should have 254 hosts. But it's showing me that it's my private ip address of my linux VM but it looks like subnet. If i use ip addr command it shows my ip is `10.0.1.178/24` as show below but if i use ifconfig command it show my ipaddres is `10.0.1.178` as show below

Output of `ip addr`

```
eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9001 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 02:e4:6b:7e:e5:ea brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.1.178/24 brd 10.0.1.255 scope global dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 1928sec preferred_lft 1928sec
    inet6 fe80::e4:6bff:fe7e:e5ea/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Output of `ifconfig`

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 9001
        inet 10.0.1.178  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.1.255
        inet6 fe80::e4:6bff:fe7e:e5ea  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:e4:6b:7e:e5:ea  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 782364  bytes 646522004 (646.5 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 363184  bytes 42400501 (42.4 MB)
```

Answer (score 2):

The outputs of `ip addr` and `ifconfig` are equivalent but slightly different notations of the same IP address and network mask.

The notion

```
10.0.1.178/24
```

means your IP address is `10.0.1.178`, and the network mask for your network consists of the first 24 bits of the address. This is the same as the statement

```
inet 10.0.1.178 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

of the `ifconfig` output, only in a more compact notation, and means that as far as the Kernel routing table is concerned, your IP address is considered as belonging to a subnet that can host up to 254 different computers, whose addresses may range from `10.0.1.1` to `10.0.1.254`.

The netmask information is relevant for the kernel when trying to determine if it is possible to reach a given remote address you want to open a connection to. An address such as `10.0.1.25` e.g. is immediately reachable since it belongs to the same subnet as your own computer, but in order to reach, say, `10.0.2.105` an appropriate route must be configured.

You may want to look at [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork#Internet_Protocol_version_4) or [this article on routing](https://opensource.com/business/16/8/introduction-linux-network-routing) for further reading.

Answer (score 0):

The second part after the forward slash is the mask for your subnet --in other words, the available number of addresses on your private network. It your case this is 256. Check out this subnet cheat sheet: https://www.aelius.com/njh/subnet_sheet.html

Comment: Arguably it's 254 "_available number of addresses_" rather than 256, because x.x.x.255/24 is the broadcast and x.x.x.0/24 is the network

Comment: @roaima.  IMHO, 256 is correct for "available number of addresses", i.e. the address block. If you mean usable addresses assignable to a host, then 254 is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

ip(8) is the native Linux network manipulating utility belongs to iproute2 project. It can be used to interact with kernel NETLINK socket to control Linux network things.

ifconfig(8) is a BSD compatible network manipulating utility, it is just a wrap of iproute2.

In short:
ifconfig(8) is a subset if ip(8), we keep it for compatibility.

TIP: Use ip(8) over ifconfig(8) if possible.